# Search a file in a library Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Running the query :
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='File.txt')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q=%27File.txt%27))
It works in graph explorer, but when I try to run the same in console application with proper AuthProvider and Permissions, it is giving access denied error.
Used documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Gave all the App permissions ...
Is there any other way to check if a file is present in a library or not ?

Comment: you need to provide your code on how you are getting a token, then how you are making the request

Comment: token you get when you run the query I have written above on explorer.
and the other is from AuthProvider. Code :
 AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

                ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

                var authResult = await auth.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

                var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;